# Fix blank PDF pages with R

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a one file PDF with R.

I'm using `pdf()`, `pie()` and `dev.off()`, but all the pages in my PDF result are blank.

This is my R code:

```
library(jsonlite)
jsons_path <- "C:/color_uses/jsons"
setwd(jsons_path)
jsons <- list.files(jsons_path, pattern=NULL, all.files=FALSE,
       full.names=FALSE)

pdf(file=paste(c("../pngs/pies.pdf"), collapse = ''), width = 1000, height = 600, onefile=T)
for(j in jsons){ 
 color_uses <- fromJSON(j)
 color_uses <- lapply(color_uses, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
})
color_uses <- do.call("rbind", color_uses)
color_uses <- as.data.frame(color_uses)
if (is.vector(color_uses$probability)) {
 color_uses$prob <- color_uses$probability
 color_uses$hex <- rownames(color_uses)
 color_uses <- color_uses[order(color_uses$probability),]

 artist_name <- gsub(".json", "", j)

 pie(color_uses$prob, col=color_uses$hex, labels=NA, main=paste(c("Colors of: ", artist_name), collapse= ''),
    cex.lab=2, cex.axis=2, cex.main=2, cex.sub=2)
}

}
dev.off()
```

What can I do to fix the blank pages, so that I can make a pie chart on each page?

Comment: Your width and height is very high. The unit is in inches.

Works your code without `pdf(....)`and `dev.off()`?

Comment: Thanks, I think the width and height was to big, yeah. I now have:
pdf(file=paste(c("../pngs/pies.pdf"), collapse = ''), width = 10, height = 10, onefile=T)

The blank pages are gone ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your width and height is very high given that the units are specified as inches. The default value is 7 inches. So you should use a smaller value:

```
pdf(file = "path_to_your_file.pdf", width = 10, height = 6, onefile=TRUE)

# your code here

dev.off()
```